# Delegating error from writer thread of PipedWriter+PipedReader pair to the reader thread

Tags: java, multithreading, io, pipe

### What do I want?

I have a PipedWriter + PipedReader pair with two threads. I want, that the exception catched in the writer thread would be thrown on the next operation of the PipedReader wrapped into a IOException. If the PipedReader has an error on its own, the writer thread exception could be added to the suppressed exceptions.

### Why?

The problem is that if an error happens in the writing thread I can only close the writer, which results in a normal EOF on the reader side. I want the reader thread to know about the error on the writer side. But I want the user of my code should see a simple Reader. So I have to present that error as an IOException.

### Question

Do you know any kind of out of the box "error delegating pipedwriter+reader" implementation out there? How would you implement such thing in thread safe way?

Comment: The only situation where a `PipedWriter` will throw an `IOException` is when it is not connected to a reader or the reader has been closed already. In both cases, attempts to hand the exception over to the reader make no sense.

Comment: I don't expect the PipedWriter to throw any Exception. The code, which writes into the writer might fail, and if it fails, I want that on the reader side it will not occour as EOF.

Comment: I see. So how about subclassing `PipedWriter` and `PipedReader` and add the information?

Comment: Hmm. I tried that. I keep on getting lost in multithreading issues and debugging. I am working on it. Its interesting that there is no out of the box solution for such thing.

Comment: You may post the code you have so far and describe the problem(s). And I don’t think that piped reader/writer is used that often. For passing chunks of characters between threads there are other solutions which, depending on the context, might turn out to be easier and most probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I created an "ErrorDelegatingReaderDecorator":

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

class ErrorDelegatingReaderDecorator extends Reader {
    static final String ERROR_MESSAGE_WRITER_THREAD = "Error occoured on the other side of the pipe. See the cause!";
    static final String ERROR_MESSAGE_READER_THREAD = "Error occoured on the this side of the pipe. See the cause!";
    private Reader decorated;
    private Throwable delegatedThrowable;

    public ErrorDelegatingReaderDecorator(Reader decorated) {
        super();
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        Throwable originalException = null;
        int result = -1;
        try {
             result = decorated.read(cbuf, off, len);           
        }
        catch( Throwable original ) {
            originalException = original;
        }
        finally {
            throwException(originalException);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        Throwable originalException = null;
        try {
            decorated.close();          
        }
        catch( Throwable original ) {
            originalException = original;
        }
        finally {
            throwException(originalException);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void throwException(Throwable originalException) throws IOException {
        Throwable delegatedTemp = delegatedThrowable;
        delegatedThrowable = null;
        if ( originalException != null ) {
            if ( delegatedTemp != null ) {
                originalException.addSuppressed(delegatedTemp);
            }
            throw new IOException( ERROR_MESSAGE_READER_THREAD, originalException ) ;
        }
        else if ( delegatedTemp != null ) {
            throw new IOException( ERROR_MESSAGE_WRITER_THREAD, delegatedTemp );
        }
    }


    public synchronized void setDelegatedThrowable(Throwable delegatedThrowable) {
        this.delegatedThrowable = delegatedThrowable;
    }
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
    final PipedWriter pipedWriter = new PipedWriter();
    PipedReader pipedReader = new PipedReader( pipedWriter, pipeBufferSize);
    final ErrorDelegatingReaderDecorator errorDelegatingReader = new ErrorDelegatingReaderDecorator( pipedReader );

    executorService.execute( new Runnable( ) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try 
            {
                //do something that writes into the writer and can throw an error
            } catch (Exception e) {
                errorDelegatingReader.setDelegatedThrowable(e);
                LOGGER.error( "Error while processing excel file.", e );
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    pipedWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error( "Error while closing printwriter.", e );
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //Giving out the decorated reader to the reader thread.
```

### Tradeoff

Since I have to throw the exception from the finally sections of methods of the decorated reader, I have to catch `Throwable`, and I have to wrap it into `IOException`. Its a bit ugly, but it will not likely ever happen to a decorated `PipedReader`.

### Why it was not working first

Just as interesting thing I also tell, how I got an intermitting failure of giving back EOF instead of the error throwing: I used try-with-resources in the writer block. It resulted in the fact, that my writer was closed first, then I have set the error in the decorator. If between the two I have got a read, then it has become an EOF. So I replaced that with plain old finally block, and now the order is ok.